# Spring SimpleJdbcCall returns wrong value

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I call a stored procedure using SimpleJdbcCall.

```
    public Map<String, Object> callStoredProcedure(SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall, String procedureName, Map<String, Object> inParamMap) {
        log.info("Calling stored procedure with name : " + procedureName);
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
        Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.withProcedureName(procedureName).execute(in);
        return out;
}
```

Its result output is

> Key = #result-set-1, Value = [{=17.00}]

I confused that when I get the class type of Value like this.

> Class class1 = entry.getValue().getClass();

My sp returns 17.00 when I execute on database  but I got **=17.00** in jdbcCall code.

Any comment would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: What is the column type?  Or rather, what is the type being returned by stored procedure?

Comment: SP returns Numeric(8,2) value.

Comment: Did you declare your out params when you constructed your SimpleJdbcCall?  Maybe you can post how it was constructed.

Comment: No I did not declare output params when i construct.

Comment: this.simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.datasource);

Comment: You might need to do that.  Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Ok I will edit my code but I dont understand = character in front of result value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I constructed my SimpleJdbcCall from a previous project....

```
createUpdateUsersSP = new SimpleJdbcCall(contactManagerJdbcT)
                .withProcedureName(pb.getCreateUpdateUsersSp())
                .declareParameters(
                        new SqlOutParameter("p_user_id", Types.NUMERIC),
                        new SqlOutParameter("p_update_stamp", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlOutParameter("p_status", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlOutParameter("p_failure_reason", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("p_vonage_id", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("p_mobile_did", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("p_email_address", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("p_name", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("p_netname_id", Types.NUMERIC),
                        new SqlParameter("p_user_status", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("p_image_update_stamp", Types.TIMESTAMP),
                        new SqlParameter("p_has_profile_image", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("p_nick_name", Types.VARCHAR));
        createUpdateUsersSP.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false);
```

Do you have something similar that you can show us?

Comment: First of all I construct simplejdbccall like this this.simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.datasource);  then passed it to callStoredProcedure method.

Comment: "The meta data processing is based on the DatabaseMetaData provided by the JDBC driver. Since we rely on the JDBC driver, this "auto-detection" can only be used for databases that are known to provide accurate meta data. These currently include Derby, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, Sybase and PostgreSQL. For any other databases you are required to declare all parameters explicitly. You can of course declare all parameters explicitly even if the database provides the necessary meta data. In that case your declared parameters will take precedence."

Comment: Maybe declaring the params will help.  Can you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your store procedure only returs a single result, but the `execute` method of `JdbcCall` tries to return a *map of output params, keyed by name as in parameter declarations*. As you have no parameter declarations, you get a `ResultSet` with only line, no column name and a single value of `17.00`.

I think that you should use instead  `executeObject` that *return the single out parameter as an Object of the specified return type.*

```
String str = jdbcCall.withProcedureName(procedureName).executeObject(String.class, in);
```

or

```
double val = jdbcCall.withProcedureName(procedureName).executeObject(Double.class, in);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my work around to extract the value , since i don't see any feasible answer for the problem.

```
((Map)((List)out.get("#result-set-1")).get(0)).get("");
```

This gave the value inside the out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is my work around.

```
Map<String,Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(sqlParameterSource);

LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<?> obj = 
(LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<?>)((List<?>)simpleJdbcCallResult.get("#result-set-1")).get(0);

Array[] values = (Array[]) obj.values().toArray()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now, you can do it the following way:

```
        // Parameters
        SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("MYINPUT1", Types.VARCHAR), // Example input parameter
                new SqlParameter("MYINPUT2", Types.VARCHAR), // Example input parameter
                new SqlParameter("INPUT", Types.VARCHAR), // Input Parameters 
                new SqlOutParameter("RC", Types.VARCHAR), // maybe Return Code 
                new SqlOutParameter("OUTPUT", Types.VARCHAR), // Result-Set Mapping - this will solve the LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap
                new SqlReturnResultSet("#result-set-1", (RowMapper<YourPojo>) (rs, rowNum) -> {
                    YourPojo example = new YourPojo();
                    YourPojo.setWhatEver(rs.getInt("WHATEVER"));
                    YourPojo.setWhenEver(rs.getInt("DATE"));
                    return example;
                }) };

         SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("MYSP001").withSchemaName("SYSPROC").declareParameters(parameters);

        // Inputvalues
        Map<String, String> inParamMap = new HashMap<>();
        inParamMap.put("INPUT1", "inputvalueExample");      
        inParamMap.put("INPUT2", "inputvalueExample2");
        SqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
        Map<String, Object> resultFromSP = simpleJdbcCall.execute(source);
        List<YourPojo> mylist = (List<YourPojo>) resultFromSP.get("#result-set-1");
```